# Intersect between two vectors but should have the same index

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get the intersection between two vectors but the index in both vectors should be the same. For example:
`x` = [1  2 3  4  5 6 7  80 9  100 11  12 103 14  150 16  170 18 20 19]
`y` = [22 1 3  40 5 4 70 8  90 10  110 12 13  140 15  160 17  18 19 20]
the intesection should be [3 5 12 18] only.

My code:

```
x = [1  2 3  4  5 6 7  80 9  100 11  12 103 14  150 16  170 18 20 19];
y = [22 1 3  40 5 4 70 8  90 10  110 12 13  140 15  160 17  18 19 20];
inter = intersect(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple with logical indexing:

```
>> x = [1  2 3  4  5 6 7  80 9  100 11  12 103 14  150 16  170 18 20 19];
>> y = [22 1 3  40 5 4 70 8  90 10  110 12 13  140 15  160 17  18 19 20];
>> x(x==y)
ans =
     3     5    12    18
>> x(abs(x-y)<=3) %// or y(abs(x-y)<=3) for the y values instead of the x values
ans =
     2     3     5     6    12    18    20    19
```

Comment: Thanks @David, I am wondering if I can compare the numbers but with + and - range .. so if the range is 3 this means that we consider the numbers equal even if it is bigger or smaller by 3. example 10 and 7 are the same as the range is 3

Comment: Thanks a lot and does it works if x and y have different length?

Comment: No, but then the problem is trickier because you have to decide which elements to compare. If you need help with that, it might be better to ask a new question rather than keep changing this one.